# How to request deletion of multiple obsolete comments?

Tags: support, comment-flags

While looking at a [mediocre at best question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968228/how-to-replace-in-array-with-a-var-result-javascript) I replied to a comment from another user, who then informed me their comment was made prior to an edit. Our comments weren't very useful at that point and I suggested we delete them in a comment.

[image]

I also considered simply flagging them but was unsure. I flagged one of them as "obsolete" figuring the whole group would get removed on inspection, but I am not sure what shows up in the moderator view.

Will a moderator look at the set of comments when an obsolete flag is used, or do they only see the single comment that the flag was used on? Also, should each obsolete comment (in a set of 4 in this situation) receive an individual flag per comment or will the one flag suffice?

Comment: Right off the bat we see *just* the comments with flags, along with an excerpt of the post and an expando control. So yeah, not a whole lot of context...

Comment: @BoltClock - This doesn't happen very often, I try to post useful comments :) But the edit to the question removed the value of them in this case. So using "other" wont waste time here? I was worried it was too bland for the "other" flag.

Comment: Not a problem at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the ["What if I see someone doing something bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) page:

> If you see a post where many comments should be deleted, especially if there's an ongoing discussion, there’s no need to flag each comment. Flag the post for moderator attention, and use the “other” reason explain what's going on.

Comments can only be removed by moderators, so flagging the question for moderator attention is really the same thing as flagging a comment.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing to that. I figured using "other" might only be for more severe cases as this was clearly mild and not offensive.